# (MySQL) Stored Procedure - Looping through result

Tags: mysql, loops, stored-procedures, iteration

We're migrating and application from PostgreSQL to MySQL.
Basically, I would like to loop through a result in MySQL.

`SELECT col1 FROM table1;` <--- (1) Get the result from this query.

```
LOOP THROUGH col1Result
```

`SELECT myCol FROM table2 WHERE thisCol = col1Result` <--- Equal to every single results from the previous query.

```
END LOOP;
```

I also found this reference
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cursors.html

However, I'm stuck with this line.

```
FETCH cur1 INTO a, b;
```

Doesn't that get every single result of `cur1` into variables `a` and `b`?
How would I make sure that I'm currently on the first index of variable `a`?

Here's an example on how the result will be used on my end (Written in PostgreSQL).

```
FOR my_record IN

   SELECT DISTINCT col1
   FROM            table1
   WHERE           col2 = param1;

LOOP

   SELECT DISTINCT col4
   FROM            table2
   WHERE           col3 = my_record.col1;

   IF true THEN
      RAISE EXCEPTION '%', 'ERROR MESSAGE' || my_record.col1;
   END IF

   SELECT DISTINCT col5
   FROM            table3
   WHERE           col6 = my_record.col1;

   IF true THEN
      RAISE EXCEPTION '%', ERROR MESSAGE' || my_record.col1;
   END IF;

END LOOP;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`cur1` would read the results of the each row. Each time it loops it gets the next row. So the first time it loops it will get the first row. 
This will go on until the loop breaks or no more rows are available (in which case a No Data condition occurs.

See [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fetch.html) for more. Hope it helps.

Comment: Hello Woofmeow, thanks. I'll try the sample given in that particular link.

Comment: Your welcome @MichaelArdan . If (it helps) upvote it as the right answer so it can help others too ; else ask more ; :)

Comment: Hello again Mr. Woofmeow. I wonder what does the 'done' in the given example does. I tried the sample procedure and ended up in the error that says: Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'done' in 'field list'.

Comment: Its cool @MichaelArdan you must be overworked. We all do it :)

Answer (score 1):

Why would you use a loop when you can do the processing with a join?

```
select mycol
from table2 t2 join
     table1 t1
     on t1.col1 = t2.thiscol;
```

This works in both Postgres and MySQL.

Comment: Hi Gordon, thanks for your feedback and suggestion. Looking at the current procedure, the first SELECT statement where the column will be taken from is consisting of at least 26 lines. This includes multiple JOIN and WHERE clauses. The result from that particular SELECT statement, will be used throughout the cycle of the procedure multiple times. It would be harsh for me to maintain the procedure if I were to execute a SELECT statement every time I needed the result.

Comment: Since the number of characters in this comment box exceeds, please see my edits.